# Unable to find proper close reason

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

[Difference between relative energies in different frames of reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504369/difference-between-relative-energies-in-different-frames-of-reference)

The question should be closed as it is not programming related. I remember having an option "blatantly off topic" or similar, but I don't see it anymore. I also think the question is not worthy of being moved to another (physics) site, so the corresponding options aren't helpful.

Which vote option should I pick to close the question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you have more than 3000 rep, you can use a custom close reason.

In this case, simply point out that it is not a programming question.

It is a physics question, but as you've noted, that does not mean it will be welcome on Physics Stack Exchange. So simply write "I am voting to close this as off-topic because it is not about programming". You could add that it is about physics, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 36):

> I remember having an option "blatantly off topic" or similar, but I don't see it anymore.

You are remembering correctly, but that option isn't available to you anymore.

This is what you remember seeing:

> [image: close flag off-topic dialog]

The specific options are going to vary depending on which site you are on, as every site in the network has custom close reasons.  But the last 2 options are constant on all sites, which includes the "Blatantly off-topic" reason you remember.  This dialog is only available for users without close vote powers.  Essentially they are flagging the post to get it to the attention of people who can close questions.

For users with close vote privileges, the dialog you see is similar to:

> [image: close vote off-topic dialog]

As before the specific options will vary site-to-site due to the site specific close reasons, but if you noticed the "blatantly off-topic" reason has been removed and replaced with an "Other" option.  You essentially have been given the power to close a question with a custom reason.  This will leave a comment, so please remember the ["Be Nice"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy with writing a close reason.

The reason for this difference is "Blatantly Off-Topic" didn't originally exist.  A ["bug" was reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so) because flaggers did not have the ability to use custom close reasons.  This was an intentional design decision, but as a compromise, the "Blatantly Off-Topic" was added to replace it.

So for this specific post, you could write your own "Blatantly off-topic" custom close reason, and even expand on it to point to Physics.SE as a possible option.  However, you should always be very careful when recommending another site unless you are aware of what constitutes a good on-topic question on that site.  The user has already posted an off-topic question on one site, so it seems unlikely they will investigate the help center on the other site before posting.

Comment: An answer showing both paths is even better.

Comment: upvote for the freehand circles.