# How should this question be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571000/hello-guys-ive-wanted-to-develop-a-travel-blogging-app-like-polarsteps-in-andro) question.

I am not sure how I should flag questions about "how long will it take to do something". Is it just blatantly off-topic? I mean it has still kind of to do with programming?

Or is it (to waste their time) to ask for a moderator for further investigation?

Comment: simply wait, such question doesn't survive too long

Comment: And it's already deleted.

Comment: Well, that works as well :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More focused, or off topic for (custom reason.)

In reality it doesn't really matter, it'll get downvoted, closed and deleted before too long anyway.

Comment: [The custom reason isn't available when flagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362667). You can enter a custom message for the "in need of moderator intervention", but that one should definitely **not** be used.