# Which flag should be used on a topic which talks about programming but is not a question?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Being a Laravel lover, I'm careful about this tag, and today I fell onto [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970237/how-do-you-implement-dynamic-pagination-in-laravel).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the title is a question but the content is a tutorial. Then I looked for the appropriate flag but I didn't find a good one according to me:

- "Blatantly off-topic" specifies "*This question has nothing to do with programming.*" but this one talks about programming
- "Needs details or clarity" (which is the final flag) does not seem appropriate against a non-question.

So I flagged for moderator intervention but I got declined with this explanation

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags

I apologize for using this flag for non-critical use-case but I didn't understand the explanation, which is why I'm here.

Comment: You vote to close as unclear. Or flag as unclear in your case (under 3k rep)

Comment: I have encountered this before. In my case, it was a user that had just joined that day that was promoting/sharing/advertising a user-script through a question.

Comment: Under vote to close "community specific reason" there is "Other" where you can insert comments about why it should be closed. Those will actually get displayed under question comments until final close vote is cast by others

Comment: @charlietfl That's only the case when you have the VTC privilege. Otherwise [it is replaced with the "Blatantly off-topic" reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362667/479156).

Comment: @Ivar Been a very long time since I looked at what the VTC rep threshold is. Thought it was 2K and maybe it even was at one point years ago

Comment: If I came across this I'd seriously consider posting the entire body as an answer and blanking the question body with an edit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the question does not ask any question, you can flag (or vote, once you have the reputation) as "Needs details or clarity" (which until not too long ago was called "Unclear what you are asking").

This is a little bit of a [*vacuous truth*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) type situation: the statement "every question asked in the post is unclear" is true *because* there are no questions in the post.

Comment: From this point of view, it's clearer for me, thanks.

Comment: Funnily enough, every question asked in the post is perfectly clear precisely because there are no questions in the post...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Unfortunately I don't understand neither of you two. If there is no subject(ive), you can't add an adjective to it. If there is no question, *one* nor *every* question can't be clear nor unclear. The only thing which is unclear is why this was posted as a *formally* question and what the intention of this "text" posted as *formally* question is.

Comment: Also: The post technically asks a question in the title. Saying it wouldn't ask any question is wrong.

Comment: I agree that "Needs details" is the appropriate flag/vote, but disagree with the reasoning here -- there *is* a question asked, it's just in the title; however, "how do you implement...?" is a vague question and requires more details, thus the flag/vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the VTC privilege then vote to close it as "Needs details or clarity" while leaving a comment below the question.

> I am voting to close the question because it's not a question.

It's preferable compared to closing it with a custom message using
*Other - add a comment* option because that closes it with

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope
> defined in the help center

reason which is not correct in this case.

If you don't have the VTC privilege then flag it as "Needs details or clarity" and optionally leave a comment.

Comment: Why not just ask for clarification in the comment, instead of telling why you voted to close it?

Comment: Hmm..If you are flagging you can omit it because you are not actually voting but if you are voting I think it's okay to say that

Comment: I'm not saying it's outright wrong to say it. But I think it's safer to not post a comment saying that you voted to close the post :) I generally just ask for clarifications in a comment, hoping that the poster will improve their post :) I also try my best to be specific, so there's less confusion.

Comment: @Scratte: That is the standard formulation when you vote to close with the "Other" close reason. The default text in the text field that opens up when you use the "Other" close reason is preset to "I am voting to close this question because " with the cursor positioned after the space following "because", so this *strongly* encourages close voters to use that wording. It is only natural to use that same wording when you want to leave a non-system generated comment as well. Note that I am not saying that wording is good, but it is the wording suggested by the system.

Comment: "*I am voting to close the question because it's not a question.*" - Technically, OP raised a question in the title. That *is* a question, but the *formal* question post is not an on-topic one. Maybe we need some more specification here?

Comment: I also disagree with "*This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center*". The question is about programming and in an on-topic frame. What is wrong here is that the *formal* question (the way the question was posted) is off-topic IMHO.

Comment: My suggestions: "*I am voting to close the question because it's not a question as defined in the help center.*" and "*This question does not appear to be within the scope defined in the help center.*"

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The problem with this particular reason is that it's not very specific and the Question author may not understand what about their post is not "within the scope defined in the help center".

Comment: @Scratte Yes, that's what I don't like too but this is just an accommodation of mine to the given answer. Nonetheless it gives a clue that there is something wrong with the post and maybe its intention in being unspecific might be to bring OP to pay some effort to find out more about how to ask questions good and correctly on SO in general. Then s/he will also see why the question was downvoted, closed and/or deleted and will do better next time.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't understand what the question is or, as in this case, what the question title has to do with the question's content (f.e. a self-answer to the given question) then this posts "*needs details or clarity*" a.k.a. is *unclear* and should be closed as such.

The concern "Why is OP asking a question and then self-answer inside of the question?" is an example of why a question is unclear.

Also note that closing a question is different from flagging for moderator intervention. Moderators usually aren't involved to close a question, so any of such kind of flags which drag moderator intervention will probably get declined very soon (as happened here).

Going more in-depth about the specific case: OP tried to provide a self-answer inside of the question (also gave another self-answer in the answer form).

Regardless of whether this is the correct form or not (it's not, but that is not the crucial point for closing it here); the intention of the question and with that the question itself is in this constitution *unclear* and thus should be voted to close as being *unclear* a.k.a. "*Needs details or clarity*".

Answer (score -5):

I can't really judge this case, as I didn't see the question (below 10k re we can't see deleted posts), but from the description it sounds like an attempt of a self answered question, which would be ok and welcome  on SO. I have seen such cases before and tried to guide the user to expand the question and move the solution into a separate answer.

Maybe we need a "this looks like a self answered question" flag/close reason with some guidance for the user how to handle it.

It's sad and frustrating for users when they want to contribute something positive but get their (self-answered) question closed and deleted wihout understand why.

Comment: Didn't downvoted. You can find a hyperlink to the referenced question under "*[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970237/how-do-you-implement-dynamic-pagination-in-laravel)*" inside of the first sentence.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio thanks, but below 10k rep I can't see deleted posts.

Comment: Ah, yes. Maybe that is why the downvotes were for? I guess, next time you should explain that better. I added a screenshot to the question.